# Java insertion sort not working properly

Tags: java, insertion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcxar.png)

This is the code screenshot link.

I am edit many time but every time the output is not completely sorted.

Comment: Questions asking for help should contain the code that you have tried. And they should contain a proper problem description. Please read at least about ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And side note: it is almost rude to ask for ASAP answers. Answers come when they come. If you want good answers in no time, then write good questions. Yours ... is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simply: you are increasing **k** far too often within your code!

Meaning: you are already looping with k; so you got:

```
for (int k=0; k < a.length; k++) { // dont use hardcoded "9" here btw!
```

and then you have

k++ **again** in the loop body. You simply dont have to do that!

Meaning: your k is growing faster than it should. But as your loop stops when k reaches 9; you are **not** processing all elements in your array!

**Plus**: insertion sort doesn't work with iterating your array **once**!
You have to keep iterating until all elements are in their place! You really want to study/think more about this algorithm. **You**, not us that is!

And as said, dont use hard-coded limits for arrays. You already say once that your array should contain 10 elements. From there on, you should be using a.length only! Besides: only use one-letter names for loop counters and such things. "a" is a pretty bad name for an array; why dont you call it "numbers" for example.